# Which of following is best way to query elasticsearch from python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

The official elasticsearch python client

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
result = es.get(index="test_index", id=1)
print(result)
```

or

```
import urllib2
import json
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:9200/test_index/_search?q=_id:1', )
result = json.loads(response.read())
print(result)
```

Which of above is best way to query elasticsearch from python?

Comment: Using the official client is generally a better idea than manually calling the API. Why would you use the second one?

Comment: @Sahand, the official elasticsearch api is released just few months ago (Sep 2013). Until that python applications use elasticsearch with something other than 'official python elasticsearch api'. So i am wondering is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few python clients, the official one is probably going to be the most reliable/consistent and if you looked at the [source code](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py) it would be doing something similar to your 2nd example. Here are some other Python clients -

1. elasticsearch
2. pyelasticsearch
3. rawes